# How do I interpret the posterior in a GLM of the lognormal family?

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, posterior, lognormal-distribution

How do I interpret the posterior in a GLM of the lognormal family?
I collected some data that is bound at zero and skewed to the left. I therefore assumed Y  to be lognormal distributed and run a model via the brms package with a GLM of the lognormal family and identity link. As far as I understood it, I am now not estimating the mean and variance of a normal distribution, but two scale parameters for the lognormal distribution. 
How do I interpret the output from brms now? Using the summary() function on the brms object, I get an Estimate for each parameter and an estimated error. Is this now the estimated value of the first scale parameter? Do I need to transform the estimated error  to derive the second parameter of the lognormal distribution?
If I sample from the posterior and cut of the lower and upper 2.5%, do I get the credibility interval for the mean effect of the parameter on Y, or do I get the credibility interval for plausible ranges of the first scale parameter? 
I am fairly new to bayesian analysis and only have done some "cookbook" GLM stuff like logistic regression. Could anybody clarify how I can make sense of the output? I coded an example in R to illustrate my problem:

```
library(brms)

a <- 1
b <- 0.5
x <- c(1:10)
error <- rlnorm(1000,0,1)
y <- a+b*x+error
df <- data.frame(y,x)
plot(density(y))

GLM.Model1 <- brm(formula=y~x,,
prior=c(
  set_prior("normal(0.5,2)",class="b",coef="x")
),
data = df, family = lognormal(),
warmup = 500, iter = 1000, chains = 4,
control = list(adapt_delta = 0.98),
cores = getOption("mc.cores", 3L))


### what exactly do "x=0.11" and the density Plots tell me? 
### The mean tendency should be 0.5 but I get .11 which seems to be the 
### plausible range for the first scale parameter?

summary(GLM.Model1)
p1 <- posterior_samples(GLM.Model1)
p2 <- mean(p1$b_x)
p3 <- mean(p1$sigma)
x11()
plot(density(p1$b_x))

curve(dlnorm(x,p2,p3),from=0,to=16)
abline(v=0.5)

# the plotted lognormal density curve hardly includes 0.5
```

Comment: Do you understand how to interpret parameters of a log normal distribution? If so, is your question just how to describe the posterior distributions for those parameters?

Comment: Yeah thats exactly my problem. How do I make sense of the parameters of the log normal distribution? I fiddled around with different values for rlnorm(1000,x,y) with different x and y values but really could not make much sense of it. I *think* I know how I would describe the posterior distribution for the parameters if I was talking about a normal distribution, something like "the plausible range of the mean effect of X on Y is between some cutoffpoint in the posterior" but I am not sure how to talk about this for the estimates of the lognormal

Comment: The log normal parameters are just the parameters of a normal distribution that has been exponentiated. It may be most useful to just transform your data using a log transform and interpret the logged-mean and logged-standard deviation as you would for a normal distribution.

Comment: Would this also imply that the log of the current posterior distribution for a parameter would give me the distribution of plausible mean values?